# How to include linux platform compatible static library in Cygwin platform

Tags: linker-errors

-I have a Linux platform compatible static library, and I have a source code which I compiled on Linux platform with proper linking static library in makefile at the linker stage and it is compiled successfully,

-But I want to compile the same source in Cygwin platform(as this is my project requirement), but I'm not able to include Linux compatible static library in Cygwin platform(Cygwin 32-bit as well 64-bit).

-As I'm getting **skipping incompatible** Error during liker stage

-what should I have to do, any alternate solution for this or need to do follow some other stapes?

what should I have to do, can anyone please suggest.

Thaks in advance :)

Comment: You can't just copy libraries, object files or executable files between different operating systems or platforms. You need to *recompile* or *rebuild* them.

Comment: is there any appropriate way to covert libecc.lib(which is compatible to Linux) to libecc.a(Which is compatible to Cygwin), because I haven't source that library, I have only this library package.

Comment: You do know that static libraries on Linux *also* have the suffix `.a`? A library named `libecc.lib` I would assume would be a Windows library.

Comment: And no, there's no way to convert any library between incompatible platforms. If the supplier of the library doesn't have a Cygwin or Windows library, then you can't use it with Cygwin or Windows.

Comment: I apology for above comments,
 Linux has the suffix .a and Windows have the .lib,

thanks for your helpful reply.

one more question :
-Is there any way to build source from Linux platform and run that binary in Cygwin platform?

Comment: Then you need a *cross-compiler* that can target Windows and Cygwin. You still can't use the library though, as it's not built for that target.